# Mobile Navigation closes after clicking on sub navigation item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have already tried to do research to fix this problem but no fixes were working! I am using a Bootstrap 3 navigation for my site and it works great on desktop. However, in the mobile menu, I click on an item, expecting the sub nav to appear, and the whole menu closes instead - after first flashing the text of the sub nav for a millisecond. How can I fix this??

Thanks

Edit: here is my navbar setup

```html
    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        
        <div class="container">
            
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-main-collapse">
                        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                    </button>
                  
                    <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="http://totango2015.staging.wpengine.com/">
                        <img src="http://totango2015.staging.wpengine.com/wp-content/themes/totango/assets/img/global/totango_logo.png" class="top-logo" />
                    </a>

                </div>
            
   
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right navbar-main-collapse">

 <ul id="menu-primary-navigation" class="nav navbar-nav"><li class="menu-product"><a href="/product">product</a></li>
<li class="menu-customers"><a href="/success-stories">customers</a></li>
<li class="dropdown menu-resources"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#">resources <b class="caret"></b></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
 <li class="menu-customer-success-resources"><a href="http://customer-success-resources.totango.com">customer success resources</a></li>
 <li class="menu-events-webinars"><a href="http://customer-success-resources.totango.com/h/c/184899-upcoming-events-and-webinars">events &#038; webinars</a></li>
 <li class="menu-totango-support"><a href="http://support.totango.com">totango support</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="menu-blog"><a href="http://totango2015.staging.wpengine.com/blog/">blog</a></li>
<li class="dropdown menu-company"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#">company <b class="caret"></b></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
 <li class="menu-about-us"><a href="http://totango2015.staging.wpengine.com/about-us/">about us</a></li>
 <li class="menu-news"><a href="http://totango2015.staging.wpengine.com/press-news/">news</a></li>
 <li class="menu-careers"><a href="http://totango2015.staging.wpengine.com/jobs/">careers</a></li>
 <li class="menu-contact-us"><a href="http://totango2015.staging.wpengine.com/contact-us/">contact us</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li class="menu-login"><a href="https://app.totango.com/login">login</a></li>
</ul>            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
<hr class="nav-rule">
            </div>
        
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>
```

Comment: How can we help without seeing what you have so far?

Comment: @APAD1 i'm new - i've added my navbar code